# In Java, can anyone explain why this object is null?

Tags: java, exception, null

```
class Monitor {
  TheManager manager;
  Map<String, Subject> subjectMap;
  public Monitor() {
    TheManager manager = new TheManager();
    Map<String, Subject> subjectMap = new HashMap<String, Subject>();
  }

  public void addObject(String objName, Object obj) {
    if(objName == null) System.out.println("name null");
    if(obj == null) System.out.println("obj null");
    if(manager == null) System.out.println("manager null");
    manager.addObject(objName, obj);
  }
}
```

I am getting a Null Pointer Exception, because manager is null. I have instantiated an object of Monitor elsewhere in the code. When I try and use the method "addObject", it gives me the NPE, just before printing "manager null" (because it is, apparently).

I feel like I'm missing something very basic here... can anyone help?

Comment: Note that if you had made manager and subjectMap `final`, then the compiler would have caught your error.

Comment: Can you explain why that is? As in, what final does?

Comment: `final` requires that you assign to the variable exactly once. In the case of a class member, it forces you to make the assignment in the constructor, which would be a reasonable thing to do in this code snippet, although not necessarily in your finished code. If you forget to assign the member then the class will fail to compile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your constructor contains

```
TheManager manager = new TheManager();
```

instead of

```
this.manager = new TheManager();
```

Same game for `subjectMap`.

Comment: `this.` is of course not strictly necessary, but it does help make it more explicit in this case.

Comment: I thought objects are declared: type name = new type();
Why would we use the keyword "this"?

Comment: You don't "declare objects". What you did is: a) "declare a new reference" (the `type name` part) together with b) "create a new instance" (the `new type()` part) and c) "point the reference to the instance" (the ` = ` part). Accidentally the name of the new reference "hides" the variable in the object. So a) is not necessary because you already have a reference - the in your `Monitor` instance. Then c) is wrong, you want `Monitor.manager` to point to the new instance.

Answer (score 2):

You do never assign manager, i.e., the field of the object.
In your constructor, you are assigning a local variable instead.
The variable shadows your field.

Answer (score 1):

You are defining `manager` and `subjectMap` twice. Once inside the constructor and once in the class. When you assign them in the constructor, they are within the scope of the constructor, and not the class. You need to remove the declarations within the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain it in Java, but I can in English :P

Notice that you have an instance variable

```
TheManager manager;
```

Which is not set to anything.  Then in your constructor you create a *different* variable:

```
TheManager manager = new TheManager();
```

Which falls out of scope at the end of the constructor.  In order to refer to the instance variable, instead of a new local one, remove `TheManager` from the beginning of the line in your constructor.